# Compute the difference matrix between a matrix and another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, distance, euclidean-distance

Given a matrix `A` in matlab with:

```
3   1
4   5
7   8
```

and another matrix `B` which could be referred to as some reference points (each row is reference point that is to be compared to each row of `A`),

```
1   1
1   2
```

I need to compute a matrix `C`, such that

```
 4    5
25   18
85   72
```

Where each row of `C` is the difference (squared L2 norm) between each row of `A` and the rows of `B`. One possible way to do this in MATLAB is to first create a zero matrix `C`, `C = zeros(5,2)`, and then use double for-loops to fill in the appropriate value. Is there any other efficient/simpler way in MATLAB?

Find the code snippet below

```
C = zeros(5,2)
for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:rows2
        C(i,j) =  (norm(A(i,:)-B(j,:)))^2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `bsxfun` like below

```
A = [3,1; 4,5;7,8];
B = [1,1;1,2];

% you can first rewrite A and B in complex coordinates to simplify the computation, and then compute difference of two complex values
C = abs(bsxfun(@minus,A*[1;1j],transpose(B*[1;1j]))).^2;
```

and you will get

```
C =

    4.0000    5.0000
   25.0000   18.0000
   85.0000   72.0000
```

Comment: Looks short and Simple! What happens in the case when I am to compute the gaussian similarity instead of just euclidean distance, `K_rbf = exp(-(norm(A(1,:)-B(2,:))^2)/(2*sigma^2))` and  `sigma`  is the euclidean distance  between each point.

Comment: @JesujobaALABI is `sigma` the matrix `C` as the matrix of euclidean distance? If yes, maybe you should try `K_rbf = exp(-(norm(A(1,:)-B(2,:))^2)./(2*C))`

Comment: Sigma can be seen as the C we have computed earlier. Using `K_rbf = exp(-(norm(A(1,:)-B(2,:))^2)./(2*C))` means that I would still use the 2 for-loops and the initialization of a matrix with zeros right? However, can i use `C = exp((abs(bsxfun(@minus,A*[1;1j],transpose(B*[1;1j]))).^2)/2*sigma);` when sigma is just a scalar?

Comment: @JesujobaALABI yes, you can do it like that when `sigma` is a scalar

Answer (score 3):

A solution similar to [ThomasIsCoding's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047901/7328782), but generalized to any number of dimensions (=columns). Thomas' answer requires `A` and `B` to have exactly 2 columns to use the complex representation. Here, we use a 3rd array dimension instead of complex values:

```matlab
n = 3; % number of spatial dimensions for computing the L2 norm
A = 10*rand(20,n);
B = 10*rand(4,n);
C = sum((reshape(A,[],1,n) - reshape(B,1,[],n)).^2,3)
```

First we reshape `A`, such that its rows remain rows, but its columns are arranged along the 3rd array dimension. We reshape `B` similarly, but its rows become columns, and its columns are moved to the 3rd dimension. This arrangement of the first two dimensions match that of the output `C`.

Next we take the difference (using implicit singleton expansion, for older versions of MATLAB you'd need to use `bsxfun`), square, and sum along the 3rd dimension.

Comment: `n = 3; % number of dimensions` isn't this the number of columns?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, it's the number of dimensions in the computation of the Euclidean distance. I see I use "dimension" in two different ways... let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: Looks cool! What happens in the case when I am to compute gaussian similarity instead of just euclidean distance, `K_rbf = exp(-(norm(A(1,:)-B(2,:))^2)/(2*sigma^2))`

Comment: @JesujobaALABI: `C` is the square norm, so you just need to do `exp(-C/(2*sigma^2))`.